# How do you send the same email to multiple recipients with Sendmail using Perl?

Tags: perl, email, sendmail

I have the following PERL script, but I can't seem to get it to send to more than one email at once. How do I send to multiple emails, preferably as separate emails?

```html
open(SENDMAIL, "|/usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t") || die "Cannot open sendmail output";

print SENDMAIL  <<"ENDENDEND";
From: <test\@test.com>
To: <test1\@test1.com>
Subject: report spam
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
  boundary="DeathToSpamDeathToSpamDeathToSpam"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--DeathToSpamDeathToSpamDeathToSpam
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


--DeathToSpamDeathToSpamDeathToSpam
Content-Type: message/rfc822
Content-Disposition: attachment

ENDENDEND

while (<STDIN>) {
        print SENDMAIL ;
}


print SENDMAIL  <<"ENDENDEND";

--DeathToSpamDeathToSpamDeathToSpam--
ENDENDEND

close (SENDMAIL);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't send mail using `/usr/lib/sendmail`. There's security problems, and it's probably going to be rejected as spam. Instead use something like [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender) or [Mail::Send](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/MailTools/lib/Mail/Send.pod).

Comment: I'm with @schwern here. Don't do this. Avoid this. Run away from this code. It's 2016 and there's a multitude of very good libraries that will help you properly compose and deliver email messages. This is the kind of stuff that caused no end of security problems in the 1990s and it's a hazard you're best to avoid.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your comments! This is code provided by SpamCop for forwarding emails to them via cPanel. I'm not really a programmer, so I would not know how to implement something else from scratch. :(

Answer (score 0):

Sending a mail by executing the sendmail program can do only a single mail at a time because that's how the sendmail program works: the mail gets piped into sendmail and the mail is done on EOF. This means you need to invoke sendmail again for the next mail.

Another way would be to not execute sendmail for delivery but directly talk to a SMTP server using [Net::SMTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP) or similar modules - this way you could also send multiple mails within a single SMTP connection.

EDIT: as noted in a comment by [Andrzej A. Filip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2139766/andrzej-a-filip) one call sendmail with the `-bs` option so that it works as a minimal SMTP server which expects communication with stdin and stdout. This feature seems to be implemented also in the sendmail wrapper from Postfix which is probably more in use than the [original sendmail](http://sendmail.org). 
But, I'm not aware of any module which supports this mode of operation so you are on your own to setup the bidirectional communication with maybe [IPC::Open2](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open2) and then speak the [SMTP protocol](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt) including all the strange end of mail handling and escaping rules. It would be much easier to just talk SMTP to the mail server on localhost using [Net::SMTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP) which already cares about all the protocol specific stuff and lets you just send the mails.

Comment: It is possible to talk to sendmail (by sendmail.org) using SMTP via its stdin and stdout. See `sendmail -bs`

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: thanks for pointing out this feature. I've included it in the answer.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your advice. I see. I am not a coder, so I was just using the script provided by SpamCop for forwarding emails to them via cPanel. I'm not sure how I would implement this via SMTP?

Comment: @user2694249: The documentation for Net::SMTP actually contains example code on how to use it. But the question for me is: since you are not a coder why do you want to code it? Why not just use the script you have working for a single mail and simply call this script for each mail you want to sent? Why do you need to be able to handle multiple mails inside the same script?

Comment: Hi Steffen! I want to be able to send one email to SpamCop and a copy to Knujon.

Comment: @user2694249: if you want to send a copy of the mail why not simply add a Cc or Bcc to the mail? Or if you don't want this just invoke the same script again but with a different recipient?

Comment: Hi Steffen! That's what I've been trying to do, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried adding another To: field, putting two emails in the To: field, adding a BCC: field, but it only send the first email, not the second.

Comment: @user2694249: please add exactly what you've tried to your question and please adjust the question (or ask a new one) so that it actually reflects what you want to do. As it stands now it just says that you want to sent multiple mails and not that you want to send the same mail to multiple recipients - which is a lot different.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "Cc: " seems to work in this instance.

For some reason, using Bcc: or adding another To: email does NOT work, but Cc: seems to do it.